# Easy user web-interface with table entry in Python

Tags: javascript, python, user-interface

I have scripts which take tabular data (from Excel) as input and produce output data as tables again. I'm thinking of learning some Python webframework to realize this as a small web interface. However, I will need excel-like functionality like multiple tables in tabs, sorting by rows, filtering data (multiple columns), changing cells with selectable values and maybe highlighting cells.

Provided I do not need any other functionality, could you suggest the quickest way to realize this, i.e. the most basic webframework that maybe still provides a useful *class for that kind of tables*?

I can find resources myself, but it would help a lot if someone could name the features I have to look out for so that I can skip learning information that I won't need for that particular task.

Comment: You may have a look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). It's a very good microframework that provides all what you need for doing web apps in Python, including Jinja2 template engine, RESTful routing, debugger and so on and so forth. Very pleasant to work with, quick to grasp and rapid to dev. About you UI needs, I don't think that you will handle your table server-side, so you should have a look at some javascript / jquery libs for that instead ... I think there are plenty of them out there.

Comment: I've been looking into SlickGrid (https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) to do the heavy lifting in JS  for excel-like table formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you will need more JS then Python.
You can use minimal python web framework - [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

And then employ full power of YUI3 Javascript framework that has excellent support for tables out of the box (including sorting).

Here are the docs for YUI3 datatable: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/

Regarding the multiple excel-like sheets - just create several tables and put them in [tabs](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tabview/).